# Remove specific compiled template with Twig 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a system that allows users to edit specific templates files from the GUI. After changing a template, the cache (compiled template) for that template file has te be cleared. In the previous version of Twig I was used to doing something like:

```
/**
 * @var Twig_Environment $twig
 */
$cache = $twig->getCacheFilename('path/to/template/here.html.twig');

if (file_exists($cache)) {
    unlink($cache);
}
```

However, in Twig 2 the `getCacheFilename` was removed from the Twig_Environment. How can we clear the cache for a specific template using Twig 2?

Comment: check if [this](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2409) could be helpful

Comment: You could do something like `unlink((new \ReflectionClass($twig->getTemplateClass('path/to/template/here.html.twig')))->getFileName());` - Did not test this out though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually managed to construct the cache filename using the following code:

```
    $mainCls = $twig->getTemplateClass($path);
    $cache = $twig->getCache(false)->generateKey($path, $mainCls);

    if (file_exists($cache)) {
        unlink($cache);
    }
```

No idea why such an important method was removed from the API.

Comment: `getTemplateClass` is marked as internal, which is a bit of a pain. However, this is a great answer and works fine! Should be a documented non-internal function.